# Python, библиотека для визуализации линейных трансформаций

Tags: python, матрицы, вектор, линейная-алгебра

Подскажите, пжлста, есть ли для питона библиотека для работы с матрицами? Заточенная под линал, чтобы в 2 и 3-х мерных пространствах можно было визуализировать линейные трансформации.

Comment: Для работы с матрицами numpy.

Comment: Для визуализации matplotlib

Comment: Numpy, pandas, matplotlib ;)